# HTML column sum

Tags: php, html, sum

This may not be possible at all, but I thought I'd ask. Can I sum an HTML table column to get a total? For example take the screen shot below and total the hours where the in/out is equal to "2400-Orchard."?

[image]

I'm new to this stuff, so any suggestions would be great.

Comment: yes, it is possible.(you can use _JavaSript_,for example)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No, you can't do it automatically in HTML. Either do it in the application that creates the table, or do it in Javascript on the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible using Javascript.

Here is link to a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PSck7/) example.

There are three divs, each with the same class and containing a unique value.

```
<div class="cell">10</div>
<div class="cell">20</div>
<div class="cell">30</div>
```

jQuery is used to select all the elements with the class "cell" and then get the text, convert it to a number (an integer in this case) and sum the values.

```
var sum=0

$(".cell").each(function(i) {
   sum = sum + parseInt($(this).text());
});

console.log(sum)
```

The final sum is printed to the browser console.

Edit:

Here is an edited [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PSck7/1/) where the sum is added to the webpage using jQuery's append function.